# HeaderText in Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex

Can i add two header text in Datagrid? My Requirement is to have two Headercolumns in a Datagrid. Is it possible?

Comment: are you looking for something like this... http://www.shuasolutions.com/FA/dg.png  You can do this with the advancedDatagrid

Comment: yes i am looking like that... can u show me an example

Comment: check out this example: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_02.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try using DataGridItemRenderer or Advanced data grid ..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is column groups that are available with the AdvancedDataGrid. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_09.html

```
   <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG"
        dataProvider="{dpFlat}"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:groupedColumns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Revenues">    
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Actual"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Estimate"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>    
        </mx:groupedColumns>
   </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```